# How to Stack Arrays on top of Each Other

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to stack 2 arrays ((4x1) and (3x1)) on top of each other, like so:

```
q = [1,
     2,
     3,
     4]

o = [5,
     6,
     7]

qo = [1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7]
```

However when I try to do this via: `q0 = np.stack((q, o))`
I get the error: `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`.

Honestly, I'm not even sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

```
Output of print(q) is
1
2
3
4

Output of print(o) is:
5
6
7
```

Comment: Try `np.hstack([q, o])`

Comment: Thanks, but got another error: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)

Comment: Can you upload the output of `print(q)` and `print(o)` each, instead of the sample you provided?

Comment: Can't provide much for the output, as the data is constantly changing (always in the same 4x1 / 3x1 matrix though). I edited my question, but it's still based on the same sample.

Comment: Can you create example data that someone else could use, exactly as described, to reproduce the exact behaviour you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting in case someone else needs the answer.

```
qo = np.concatenate((q, o))
```

This is what worked for me.